# Cast NSWindow to NSPanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

I am accessing a Virtual keyboard (external application - in Adobe Flex). 
I want that keyboard should be non focusable. So I have to apply

```
styleMask:NSNonactivatingPanelMask
```

But am accessing the keyboard as

```
NSWindow *myMainWindow = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
```

as NSNonactivatingPanelMask  can only be applied to the NSPanel only

If I can type cast the NSWindow to NSPanel (?) then it possible.

----------My Previous question------------

[Return focus to Editor after clicking a button in floating window of MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902219/return-focus-to-editor-after-clicking-a-button-in-floating-window-of-mac)

Comment: a cast never really _changes_ the type of on object. it just changes how you look at it so casting won't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS provided by @ashirbad

```
NSWindow *mainWindow = [[NSApp windows] objectAtIndex: 0];
NSView *mainContentView = [mainWindow contentView];

NSPanel *mainPanel = [[NSPanel alloc] initWithContentRect:[mainContentView frame]
             styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSNonactivatingPanelMask
            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];

[mainPanel setContentView:mainContentView];
[mainPanel setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel];

[mainPanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[mainContentView orderOut:nil]; //error
```

---

This solved my problem.
But I'm getting an error orderOut is not defined in NSView.

If the top app is a Mac application then it's ok But if it is a flex app (in this case). The application not responding at this line.

```
[mainPanel setContentView:mainContentView];
```

Answer (score 3):

An `NSPanel` is an `NSWindow`, the reverse is not true - inheritance doesn't work both ways!

Furthermore casting an object reference from one type to another does not change the actual type of the reference object, so even if you cast an `A *` to a `B *` then invoking a method gets you exactly the same method as without the cast - the cast serves to inform the compiler that you know the actual object referenced is a different type and so quietens the compiler when you invoke a `B` method.

Even if you could get past all that, you state you want the keyboard to be non-focusable, which is not the same as non-activating - the former is about being an applications *main window*, the latter is about accepting input without activating an application.

The *main window* of an application is the one which is focussed, its frame highlighted in some way, etc. The *key window* of an application is the one which is accepting user input. They are often the same window, but need not be. It sounds like you want your keyboard to by the key window without being the main window - i.e. behave like a panel.

`NSWindow` has methods `canBecomeMainWindow` and `canBecomeKeyWindow` which determine whether a window can become main or key respectively. While you cannot change what these return for an `NSWindow` instance you can subclass `NSWindow` and override these methods - this is what `NSPanel` does - see the `NSWindow` documentation for these methods. So if you, say, define `KeyboardWindow` as an `NSWindow` subclass and override `canBecomeMainWindow` to return `NO`. Do this and you have a window which will not become main (focussed) but can accept input.

HTH

Comment: Can I access external application as NsPanel Object ?

Comment: An application can have windows, but an application is not a window so you cannot access it as one - what would that even mean? So your question does not make sense as written, maybe you are asking something different? If you've another question open a new question, don't ask it as a comment as people will not see it.

Comment: My Flex Application should receive keyboard input without activating the owning application. The Flex Application is written in Adobe Flex when it runs I have call ANE (Native Call to Library), where I have to access this Flex application (Topwindow) and set 'NSNonactivatingPanelMask'